# Flow accumulation algorithm open source code in C++ on Windows

Tags: dem, hydrology, flow-accumulation

I'm looking for **flow accumulation** *open source implementation* ( C++ or C# would do, Python no), on ***Windows***, preferably the source code comes with Visual Studio project files so that I can just build and run immediately.

This is my actual problem statement:

> I have a terrain ( in the form of mesh/element), and I want to
>   indicate how the water flows in the terrain, subjected to gravity
>   force and the terrain condition ( of course).
>
> A crude way of doing this is to take every single mesh element, then
>   draw the water flow direction from the highest point to the lowest,
>   but I think this will result in a lot of ugly arrows that although can
>   roughly point towards the correct directions, but really don't look
>   nice when view as a whole.

I've asked [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/29529/690) at **Computational Science Stack Exchange**, but I reask here because I wonder whether there is any other flow accumulation option *besides* [RichDEM](https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flow_accumulation.html), which I've some trouble with because I am not familiar with GCC compiler used to compile it, and also because I'm not too familiar with the R tools.

Comment: Would an open source D8/Dinfinity/FD8 flow accumulation tool implemented in the Rust language do? If so, see here: https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools/tree/master/src/tools/hydro_analysis

Comment: @WhiteboxDev, don't think so, because I would want to distribute it to other Windows machines too; I can't just simply install python or Rust runtime so carefreely

Comment: Rust doesn't have a runtime. It creates stand-alone compiled binaries the same way C++ does. Your users don't have anything to install. See here https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/ for more details.

Comment: Take a look at the Windows download of the WhiteboxTools library here: http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/WhiteboxTools/download.html Specifically see the D8, DInfinity, and FD8 flow accumulation tools. There's also tools in there for hydrological preprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being I'm sticking with [TauDEM](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/index.html). Written in C++, it exists as command line utilities.

It contains `D8`, `DInf` implementation, which is sufficient for me needs, for now.

Since the source code is available, one can also take the source code and build it into a library.